# How does contribution.repeattransaction set the invoice_id?

Tags: civicontribute, api, recurring-contributions, invoice

Upon calling the API's contribution.repeattransaction, the original contribution record seems to get copied correctly, with the exception of invoice_id. Here is what I'm doing:

`$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'repeattransaction', array(
            'sequential' => 1,
            'original_contribution_id' => $original_contribution['id'],
            'contribution_status_id' => "Completed",
            'trxn_id' => $transaction_id, //Insert new transaction ID
        ));`

This copies the original contribution values and properly inserts the new transaction ID. However, invoice_id is NULL in the database.

If I try to pass invoice_id...

`$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'repeattransaction', array(
            'sequential' => 1,
            'original_contribution_id' => $original_contribution['id'],
            'contribution_status_id' => "Completed",
            'trxn_id' => $transaction_id, //Insert new transaction ID
            'invoice_id' => $new_invoice_id //and new invoice ID
        ));`

...nothing changes. In the civicrm_contribution table, invoice_id is again NULL for the contribution that was just inserted.

Does anyone know how I'm supposed to repeat the transaction and set invoice_id properly?

P.S. I've been looking inside CRM_Core_Payment_BaseIPN->completeTransaction(), but can't see where the invoice_id is handled (if it is).